# Access Vue.js plugin from main.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a plugin and I just wonder why I can't access it in `main.js` file. Here's how `Auth.js` looks like:

```
const Auth = {
    install(Vue) {

        Vue.prototype.$isGuest = function () {
            console.log('This user is a guest.');
        }

        Vue.prototype.$getAuthToken = function () {
            console.log('Auth token will be returned.');
        }

    }
}

export default Auth
```

This is main.js:

```
import Auth from '@/helper/Auth'
Vue.use(Auth)
```

However, when I execute `console.log(this.$isGuest())`, it doesn't work. It actually returns the following:

`main.js?1c90:25 Uncaught TypeError: this.$isGuest is not a function`

The problem is that this method works when I call it in components such as `Dashboard.vue` and things like that.

I have a way to avoid calling `isGuest` method within `main.js` (I can call it in `Layout.vue`), but I'm more curious why it doesn't work in `main.js`.

Maybe because Vue hasn't been initialized yet, but even if I put the `console.log()` line at the end of the file, still doesn't work.

Thanks,
N.

Comment: Where is the `console.log` in main.js?

Comment: @Bert below ```Vue.use(Auth) ``` and above ```new Vue({...```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling `this.$isGuest()` *outside* of Vue, you will get the error you describe. That's because `this` is *not* a Vue object. What `this` is depends on how you are building your code, but given you are using `import` it's probably the module.

Also, you are adding `$isGuest` to the *prototype* of Vue. That means that the function is only going to be available on actual instances of Vue objects. That is why it is available in your components.

If you want to use it in the main script, the only place you will be able to get to it is inside the Vue object in a lifecycle handler, method, or computed. For example:

```
new Vue({
  mounted(){
    console.log(this.$isGuest()) // this should work
  }
})
```

Comment: how do you construct a new Vue? Builder tells me there's no constructor signature.